# Possible to turn a php cycle function into a double barrel system?

Tags: php

Is there a simple way to modify this php:

```
function cycleCols() {
    $p = "transparent;";
    $s = "#efefef;";
    static $lastColour;
    $lastColour = ($lastColour == $p) ? $s : $p;
    return $lastColour;
}
```

To get it to cycle like this:

```
transparent;
transparent;
#efefef;
#efefef;
transparent;
transparent;
#efefef;
#efefef;
```

Etc, instead of how it does now..

```
transparent;
#efefef;
transparent;
#efefef;
```

Etc... or does something else entirely need to be built to do this?

Comment: `return "$lastColour\n$lastColour";`

Comment: Umm yeah I see how you got that idea but I kinda simplified the question. I can't echo the value for one background='".cycleCols."' output like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function cycleCols() {
    static $colors = ['transparent;', '#efefef;'], $i = 0;
    $selectColor = ($i++/2 % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;
    return $colors[$selectColor];
}
```

Increment a counter (`$i`), divide it by 2, then check if it's even/odd.